# WPF: How to use BasedOn Style

Tags: wpf, styles, basedon

I am new to WPF and I created the following simple style example.  But it doesn't work properly and button's content doesn't show although I can still click on it.  Can anyone tell me why it is broken?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Blue" 
                            BorderThickness="5" 
                            Background="Aqua"
                            Width="80"
                            Height="40">
                        <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Grid" x:Name="GridWithMarginStyle">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="12"></Setter>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
            <EventSetter Event="Button.Click" Handler="ButtonHandler" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button Name="OkBtn">OK</Button>
    <Button Name="CancelBtn" Click="CancelBtn_Click">Cancel</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `BasedOn` property in the correct way. The problem is that your `ContentPresenter` is not binded to the control it renders (i.e. the button).

Just try to replace your `ControlTemplate` XAML with this one:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Border BorderBrush="Blue" 
        BorderThickness="5" 
        Background="Aqua"
        Width="80"
        Height="40">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

By using [TemplateBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms742882(v=VS.110).aspx) you can bind the `ContentPresenter` to the `Content` property of your templated control.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.  I have to use <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" /> instead of <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" /> to get it working.  But you give me some ideas what to do.  Thanks.

Comment: It is strange. I tried your XAML with .NET framework 4.0 and it works. Can I ask you which framework version are you using? Anyway `TemplatedParent` should work whatever version you are using. Your solution is not wrong, but AFAIK 'RelativeSource TemplatedParent' is a little be slower than using `TemplatedParent`.